# Call not establishing Android Sinch

Tags: android, voip, sinch

I am trying to build an app with app to app calling in Android using Sinch.

I have managed to implement push notifications and the incoming call screen displays on an incoming call, but when I press answer, it takes me to the Call Screen Activity but the call just stays in the initiating state. I am calling "call.answer()" and I swear my code for answering is the same as the sample code provided by sinch.

```
private void answerClicked() {
    mAudioPlayer.stopRingtone();
    Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCallId);
    if (call != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Answering call");
        call.answer();
        Log.d("calls", call.getState().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallScreenActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID, mCallId);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "call must be null");
        finish();
    }
}
```

"Answering call" is shown in the log. Any idea why it wouldn't be properly answering the call?

[image: This is what the phone looks like when it goes to CallScreenActivity.]

Comment: What is `CallScreenActivity` doing?

Comment: What do you mean?